# How to resolve warning "Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: <machine hostname>?

Tags: ansible, ansible-pull

I'm trying to use Ansible to automate my workstation. I've been following [this tutorial](https://opensource.com/article/18/3/manage-workstation-ansible) as an introduction. But I keep getting a warning using the `ansible-pull` command.

After doing `sudo ansible-pull -U https://github.com/plsergent/setup-user-friendly.git` i'm getting `[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: <local machine hostname>`

Here is my `/etc/ansible/hosts` file :

```
[localhost]
127.0.0.1

[localhost:vars]
ansible_connection=local
```

and my `local.yml` file :

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  pre_tasks:
    - name: update repositories
      apt: update_cache=yes
      changed_when: False

  tasks:
    - include: tasks/packages.yml
    - include: tasks/users.yml
    - include: tasks/cron.yml
```

Is there a way to get rid of this warning ?

Thanks

Note:
I don't have any warning when I run my playbook using `ansible-playbook`:
`sudo ansible-playbook local.yml`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to get rid of this warning ?

You're getting the warning because `ansible-pull` builds a command line that includes a `--limit` option that is built [like this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/cli/pull.py#L165):

```
node = platform.node()
host = socket.getfqdn()
limit_opts = 'localhost,%s,127.0.0.1' % ','.join(set([host, node, host.split('.')[0], node.split('.')[0]]))
```

Where `platform.node()` returns your systems node name (i.e. the output of `uname -n`) and `socket.getfqdn()` attempts to return the fully qualified domain name of your system.  This means that the ansible command line will look something like this:

```
ansible-playbook -l localhost,yourhostname.example.com,yourhostname,127.0.0.1 ...
```

It so happens that when you provide a hostname in the `--limit` argument that does not match a host in your inventory, you get the `Could not match supplied host pattern` error.  You can reproduce that like this:

```
$ ansible all -m ping  -l host-that-does-not-exist
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit
localhost does not match 'all'

 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: host-that-does-not-exist
```

If the warning really bothers you, you can avoid it by explicitly including your local hostname in the ansible inventory by adding a `-i` option to your `ansible-pull` command line. You can either include the hosts inline:

```
ansible-pull -i localhost,myhostname -U ...
```

Or you can point it explicitly at an existing inventory file:

```
ansible-pull -i /etc/ansible/hosts -U ...
```

Comment: In case anyone else gets stuck on this: it doesn't work to do:
ansible-pull -i myhostname -U ... because ansible doesn't interpret this as a list of hosts
So you need to do:
ansible-pull -i myhostname, -U ... (note trailing comma)

Answer (score 1):

To add to @larsks answer, it seems that using dynamic inventories with an ansible-pull will produce the warning even if the specified hostname is included in the results of the dynamic inventory script. Workaround is adding the hostname to the -i as previously stated.

Answer (score 0):

Beware: when both "myhost" and "myhost.example.com" are in the inventory, then ansible-pull seems to get confused about how many hosts there are, and may run plays or roles twice (once on myhost, again on myhost.example.com), or may run some plays on one name and other plays on the other name, *in parallel*, producing an unexpected execution order.

Answer (score 0):

To run Ansible on the localhost, just set your `/etc/ansible/hosts` file like this (no need of IP):

```
[all]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by adding --limit=all to the ansible-pull command.
As @larsks indicated in their answer, ansible-pull was adding a limit to the playbook command under-the-hood, but in my case (from a containerized environment), it was adding a limit to a nonexistent host:

> [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: e7b0c924b942

By overriding the limit with --limit=all, I was able to use the values in my default inventory.